# Receiving Yearling badge for 4 years one by one each day

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I've had an account here for 4 years, but only recently started using the site. And now I'm receiving Yearling badge one by one each day.

Why don't you give all of them at once?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rules for the badge are, you have to have earned 200 points for each year you've been here to qualify for "that year's" badge. Until two days ago, you didn't qualify for any of them. Then...

- ... on 2018-08-21 21:36 you exceeded 200 reputation here & qualified for your first Yearling; 5 minutes later, the badge was awarded...
- ... on 2018-08-22 13:21 you exceeded 400 reputation & qualified for your second Yearling; about 9 minutes later, you got it...
- ... today at 23:26 you exceeded 600 reputation & qualified for your 3rd Yearling - and about 4 minutes later, you got that too.

When you cross 800, you can expect to get your fourth Yearling.

### See: [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188731#188731)